# click and add div but remove it to other element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to make a script that when i click on a list it add a div inside the tag `<li>`, this one is ok, but my problem is that when i click in a other `<li>` i would like remove the div before inserted how can i do that and i would like remove the class .selected as well? Thanks.

```
$(document).on('click', '#horiz_container img', function() {
            var img_selected = $(this);
            var value_sport = img_selected.val();
            if (!$(this).closest('li').is('.selected')) {

                $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
                $(this).closest('li').prepend('<div class="selected_sport"><img src="' + CI_ROOT +'resources/img/select.png"></div>');
            }

        });
```

Comment: give your html structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '#horiz_container img', function () {
    var img_selected = $(this), $li = img_selected.closest('li');
    var value_sport = img_selected.val();
    var $selected = $('#horiz_container .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $selected.find('.selected_sport').remove();

    $li.addClass('selected');
    $li.prepend('<div class="selected_sport"><img src="' + CI_ROOT + 'resources/img/select.png"></div>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#horiz_container img', function() {
            var img_selected = $(this);
            var value_sport = img_selected.val();
            if (!$(this).closest('li').is('.selected')) {

                $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
                **$('.selected_sport').remove();**
                $(this).closest('li').prepend('<div class="selected_sport"><img src="' + CI_ROOT +'resources/img/select.png"></div>');
            }

        });
```